# Read Java class from a jar from classpath but dont load all java classes with following condition

Tags: java, jar, jvm, classpath, classloader

My issue is I want to read `Java` class from a `jar` file and `jar` file is in different path. I have to read particular `Java` class from `jar` when someone import that java package within `Java` program not the whole jar's `Java` classes (Dynamically) as `Netbeans` and `Eclipse` IDE does.

Can anyone help on this please?

Comment: Can't understand your question...please frame it with examples so people understand what you want.

Comment: Classes are loaded on demand. Even Netbeans and Eclipse Runtime does not load all classes. First try out a simple `URLClassLoader`. And if you want to restrict class loading, subclass it and override the load method to only load classes that fit your need.

Comment: Actually I am writing web based java IDE functionality where user can write java class and import classes as per his need , Now problem is all jar file are already present in  lib folder under WEB-INF in my webapplication but when I am trying to import any java api from my web based IDE it is showing "Package is not found in classpath" during compilation ,so as per my understanding it is not getting my jar file location so I want to load the perticular jar so that if someone write import com.some.example.*; then during compilation it doesn show error.